# How to mock inheritance chain in C++ with google mock

Tags: c++, mocking, tdd, googlemock

I am using google mock, and want to mock an inheritance chain like this:

```
class A
{
    // virtual method A1();
}
class B : public A
{
    // virtual method B1();
}

class C : public B
{
   // virtual method C1();
}
```

When mock A, I need to mock A1(); 
when mock B, I have to mock both A1() and B1(); when mock C, I have to mock C1(), B1() and A1().

```
//Mock Definition
class MockA : public A
{
   // mockA1()
}

class MockB : public B
{
   // mockA1()
   // mockB1()
}

class MockC : public C
{
   // mockA1()
   // mockB1() 
   // mockC1()  
}
```

However, for class C, I only care the new extended function C1(). I did not want to mock all its parent method especially when there is too many methods defined. But, I cannot instantiate the mockC class if I did not mock all the methods inherited from its parent.

One way is to to require mockC inherit from both C and mockB, However it requires both C and mockB pure inherit from B. but the C->B->A inheritance chain is defined in third party code that I cannot change.

```
// I cannot change this to virtual inheritance
class C : public virtual B
{
    //method C1();
}

class mockB : public virtual B
{
    // mthod B1()
}

class mockC: public C, public mockB
{
   // mock method C1();
}
```

Is there any good way to solve this problem?

Comment: So all the virtual methods of A and B are pure virtual?

Comment: Mocks can inherit from each other (well, not circularly), so you wouldn't have to rewrite all the methods; look at the accepted answer to: [Mock Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484906/can-a-mock-class-inherit-from-another-mock-class-in-googlemock)

Comment: D'oh, helps if I read all the way to end, about third-party code. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

Create mock only to last class in your inheritance hierarchy. Then use it in all tests that need any class in the hierarchy. According to your example you can create only mockC class:

```
class MockC : public C {
   // mockA1()
   // mockB1() 
   // mockC1()  
}
```

Then pass it to all classes you need to test that depends on *A* or *B* or *C*. This wouldn't seem illogical.